# NSDate countdown from NOW to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, countdown

How can I show a countdown in HH:mm:ss format from NOW to a desired NSDate that will happen in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a timer for ticking the date.

Store a future date, and keep on substracting future date - [nsdate today]...

Calculate the time in seconds and calculate it into Hours, minutes, seconds...

//Make two properties `NSDate *nowDate, *futureDate`

```
futureDate=...;

nowDate=[NSDate date];

long elapsedSeconds=[nowDate timeIntervalSinceDate:futureDate];
NSLog(@"Elaped seconds:%ld seconds",elapsedSeconds);

NSInteger seconds = elapsedSeconds % 60;
NSInteger minutes = (elapsedSeconds / 60) % 60;
NSInteger hours = elapsedSeconds / (60 * 60);
NSString *result= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

This will come handy for you...[kindly check the project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5387039/timerstopwatch-3-zip-43k?da=y)...

Comment: Hmm.. this result returns: -114384:00:-24 (the numbers are going up too!)

Comment: This is how I'm getting future date:     NSString *dateStr = @"15:21:00";
    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

Comment: oooppppssss...[futureDate timeIntervalSinceDate:nowDate] invert the conditions.... swap futureDate & nowDate..

Comment: Why you only taking hour,min,sec... if u take date then sustraction will be easier...

Comment: What full date format would I use then? I mean, what would I include in addition to HH:mm:ss to get a full "date"

Comment: if u store only time, how will u say 7:00 is todays evening or tomorrows morning? if you have date with timezone/stamp u can easily say all those...

Comment: Yeah, but what is considered a full date to NSDate? Just 1/18/2013 05:24

Answer (score 5):

Start at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSDate *future = // whatever

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)tmr
{
    NSTimeInterval iv = [future timeIntervalSinceNow];
    int h = iv / 3600;
    int m = (iv - h * 3600) / 60;
    int s = iv - h * 3600 - m * 60;
    aUILabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s];
    if (h + m + s <= 0) {
        [tmr invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this code a shot:

```
NSTimer* timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: [self.futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow] target: self selector: @selector(countdown:) userInfo: nil, repeats: YES];
```

The countdown: method:

```
- (void) countdown: (NSTimer*) timer
{
    if( [self.futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 0)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        return;
    }
    NSDateComponents* comp= [ [NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit startingDate: [NSDate date] toDate: self.futureDate options: 0];
    NSLog(@"%lu:%lu:%lu", comp.hour,comp.minute.comp.second);
}
```